# Change the text layout in a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, text, uitextfield

Below is an image of some UITextFields.  Regarding the large one on the bottom, how do I get it to start text at the top left (not the middle), and how do I get them all to start a bit to the right.  As you can see, they are awkwardly close to the left edge.

---

[image]

Comment: Do left padding. And for text view you have to use left inset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sublcass to a custom TextField:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    var inset:CGFloat = 12  // You can set the inset you want

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: 0)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: 0)
    }

}
```

The result, you can see the inset of the CustomTextField:

[image]

---

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: @Gabe Spound, you can search the delegate methods.

Answer (score 2):

For textField, override following methods:

```
class InsetTextField: UITextField {

    var inset: CGFloat = 10

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: 0)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: 0)
    }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: 0)
    }

}
```

For textView:

```
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(inset, inset, inset, inset);
```

And you can be involved when the textView is done editing, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132330/detect-start-and-stop-editing-uitextview).

Comment: could you provide a bit more detail?  Do i make an extension to those classes?

Answer (score 1):

By default, UITextFields only have one line. Based off your image, I'd assume you want the user to have space to type a paragraph. For paragraphs, it is better to use UITextViews. It'd be a simpler solution for your problem.

I always use TextViews for biographies because it just makes my life much easier.

Comment: I can't use a textview because I need to be able to create Actions when they are done editing, and they don't have that option.

Answer (score 1):

add left padding of your textfield

```
let paddingVie = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 10, height: 10))
yourtextField.leftView = paddingVie
yourtextField.leftViewMode = .always
```

for textview add

```
yourTextVieName.textContainerInset =
   UIEdgeInsetsMake(8,5,8,5); // top, left, bottom, right
```